# what technology is behind soccernet gamecast?

Tags: html

I am looking at JavaFX to create RIA. and technology behind partial refresh and news feed, anything that can update and display new information real time. anyone knows anything behind the technology of soccernet gamecast?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ewww...java.....

From what I understand, GameCast is built using plain old HTML/Javascript. The back end is written in ASP.Net (likely C#). Here are some resources to brush up on to get started with realtime applications:

- [Ajax Beginners Tutorial](http://www.ajaxprojects.com/ajax/tutorialdetails.php?itemid=10#start)
- [An ASP.Net AJAX example](http://encosia.com/2007/07/25/display-data-updates-in-real-time-with-ajax/)
- [Using Tomcat to run an AJAX-enabled application](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/tutorials/wa-ajax/index.html)